# Object of class ORM could not be converted to string <img src

Tags: php, html, slim, idiorm

So I'm new to a lot of this. Definitely PHP and idorm. I Searched far and wide but I'm not seeing an answer to this specific problem.

Object of class ORM could not be converted to string.

The Slim error pops up at the php code for $picture.

This is in my Html view

```
<div class="profile-left">
  <div class="profile-image">
    <img src="<?= empty($picture) ? '/static/images/profile-default.png' : $picture ?>"/>
      <i class="fa fa-user hide"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="m-b-10">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-sm" type="button" id="change_picture" data-toggle="modal" href="#change-picture-modal">Change picture</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the route for $picture in another file

```
$picture = ORM::for_table('picture')
    ->where('picture_gallery_id', $user->account_id)
    ->where('name', $user->account_id . ':profile')
    ->find_one();

$params = array_merge(
    get_base_params('account', 'Edit Profile'),
    [
        'picture' => $picture,
    ]);
```

The data itself is saved in a Postgres table as bytea.

I'm quite sure I am missing something in my noob-ishness. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the structure of the 'picture' table?  What fields are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ORM returns a picture object of some type, do a `var_dump()` the variable `$picture` and see the fields that are available if you don't know the structure of the `picture` table.

Your issue is exactly as the error indicates, `$picture` is an object, your template system expects a string (or something that casts to a string).  You want to pass in a string property of `$picture` object you want displayed:

```
  $params = array_merge(
get_base_params('account', 'Edit Profile'),
[
    'picture' => $picture->some_property,
]);
```

There is a chance the ORM library isn't finding the picture and returning an instance of itself or somehting.

Comment: I had tried something in that vein. I did this,

'picture' => $picture->data

Data being the col name of the bytea field

Comment: @BrettHuston Assuming that  `$picture->data` is a string, you  would not get the same error.

Comment: Thank you fort your quick response! I deeply appreciate it. But i'm still in the dark. What would that look like more specifically?

Comment: @BrettHuston did you `var_dump($picture)`?  Do this after theORM request but before you build the array and put the result in the question.

Comment: @BrettHuston  I suspect `$picture->data` is also an object.

Comment: array (size=7)
      'id' => int 15
      'picture_gallery_id' => int 1
      'name' => string '1:profile' (length=9)
      'mime_type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'data' => resource(78, stream)
      'created_at' => string '2016-07-22 10:04:18.044034' (length=26)
      'updated_at' => null

I'm thinking this is what you are looking for.

Comment: So @Ray If I'm understanding correctly 'data' => resource(78, stream) needs to be converted in some way?

Comment: @BrettHuston yes, it's clearly not a string.  Try using `$picture->id` and it should work without complaining.

Comment: You are right about this. Thank you for your help. it has moved me forward. I believe i'm on to another question now. I'll make a separate post after some leg work

Comment: @Ray has put you on the right track. Another solution is to define a [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method of your Picture model.